# Python: write throws "Permission Denied" when excel opens a CSV file for readonly

Tags: python

```
fd = open('example.csv', 'a')
while True:
    fd.write('...'+'\n')    
    fd.flush()
    ...
```

Now after a while if the user opens using Excel the example.csv in READONLY mode, the write sometime throws IOError (errno 13).
The behavior is inconsistent and hard to reproduce

Any ideas?

OS: Windows 7

Python: 2.7.5

Comment: @David.Zheng He says OS is Windows 7, and you talk about sudo?!

Comment: @GabiMe Did you check to run the script with administrator permission?

Comment: Even if its open in "read only" mode; you cannot write to it from another process. You can only append when you have an exlusive lock.

Comment: @SAM, he edited the description, added OS and python version.

Comment: @Burhan: No, the process writes ok most the time. Only sometimes it fails

Comment: Don't count on this behavior; it is a recipie for file corruption.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid So what might a workaround be? It sounds like you're saying if I can retain a handle from Python, the OS will still allow reading? I am appending to a CSV and also creating a ZIP file (via Python's zipfile module)... using another Python process I can read the ZIP and CSV files with no apparent problems... but as soon as the same CSV is read using Excel I get the permissions denied error.

Comment: This is because Excel opens the file with an exclusive lock.